# Can I remove VB options from the VisualStudio new project dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After two evenings of designing a new WinForms application GUI I have suddenly realized that I am doing it in a VB project I had created instead of a C# project unintentionally.

And this is not the first time such a thing happens to me.

Can I just remove the VB options from the list so prevent them being chosen accidentally?

Comment: Sounds like a case of the Ballmer peak.  Switch your preferred language to C# so it is on top.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to

- Tools
- Import and Export Settings...
- Import Selected Environment settings and click Next
- Make selection whether to save current settings and click Next
- Select C# under the Default Settings folder and click Next
- Deselect everything except for the General Settings > New Project Dialog Preferred Language entry and click Finish.

Best Regards